# Submit function stopped working when Captcha Control Added

Tags: c#, asp.net, createuserwizard

I had everything working fine then when I put in the Captcha control it stopped going to the function where it creates the user.

So if I remove the control from the aspx page it works fine and goes directly to the CreatingUser function.

-- aspx --

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
    OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" 
    OnCreatingUser="RegisterUser_CreatingUser">

 <cc1:CaptchaControl id="CControl" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaFontWarping="Low" CaptchaLineNoise="Low" CaptchaMaxTimeout="300" ></cc1:CaptchaControl>
```

--Behind Code--

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
 {
        Captcha.V2.CaptchaControl mycaptcha = (Captcha.V2.CaptchaControl)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("CControl");

        mycaptcha.Validate();

        Boolean answer = mycaptcha.IsValid;
        if (answer == false)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }   
    // Testing area where it worked before just to see...
    //
    //  .....
 }
```

Comment: is `mycaptcha.IsValid==false`?

Comment: It couldnt even check to see if it is or not.  Cause it did not even go into the RegisterUser_CreatingUser function

Comment: The CaptchaControl must be highjacking the CreateUser, or the `POST` handling all together. I'm not familiar enough to know why it wouldn't be working. Have you tried using: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet